# Android Build Error: Attribute Signature requires InnerClasses attribute. Check -keepattributes directive

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I'm facing this error when trying to build the app in release mode.

> Error: Attribute Signature requires InnerClasses attribute. Check -keepattributes directive

My `proguard-rules.pro` line looks like this:

```
-keepattributes Signature
```

what InnerClasses is the compiler referring to? What am I omitting?

Comment: Can you please have -keepattributes InnerClasses in your proguard config and check.

Comment: @kj007 yeah it worked, I was thinking it referred to some Signatures' inner classes. The way it's written is a bit ambiguous to me

Comment: I have posted my answer.

Comment: I have also added possible reason was not working Signature .

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Signature (Java 8 or higher) works only Java 8 or higher and InnerClasses (Java 5 or higher) so check your Android Studio is using Java SDK version.
Please update your Proguard config with below settings

Add this line to your `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

> InnerClasses (Java 5 or higher)
>
> Specifies the relationship between a class and its inner classes and
>   outer classes. Other than this and the naming convention with a '$'
>   separator between the names of inner classes and outer classes, inner
>   classes are just like ordinary classes. Compilers may need this
>   information to find classes referenced in a compiled library. Code may
>   access this information by reflection, for instance to derive the
>   simple name of the class.
>
> Signature (Java 8 or higher)
>
> Specifies the generic signature of the class, field, or method.
>   Compilers may need this information to properly compile classes that
>   use generic types from compiled libraries. Code may access this
>   signature by reflection.

More details about `-keepattributes` and more settings you can apply, please see below link.

[Proguard options](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage#keepoptions)

Comment: Took me a life to find this soloution

Answer (score 2):

Ref : https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#manual/usage.html

> **keepattributes [attribute_filter]**
>
> Specifies any optional attributes to be preserved. The attributes can
>   be specified with one or more -keepattributes directives. The optional
>   filter is a comma-separated list of attribute names. Attribute names
>   can contain ?, *, and ** wildcards, and they can be preceded by the !
>   negator. Typical optional attributes are Exceptions, Signature,
>   Deprecated, SourceFile, SourceDir, LineNumberTable,
>   LocalVariableTable, LocalVariableTypeTable, Synthetic,
>   EnclosingMethod, RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,
>   RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations, RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations,
>   RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations, and AnnotationDefault. The
>   InnerClasses attribute name can be specified as well, referring to the
>   source name part of this attribute. For example, you should at least
>   keep the Exceptions, **InnerClasses**, and Signature attributes when
>   processing a library. You should also keep the SourceFile and
>   LineNumberTable attributes for producing useful obfuscated stack
>   traces. Finally, you may want to keep annotations if your code depends
>   on them. Only applicable when obfuscating.

**Add This Line in proguard-rules.pro File**

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

More Details Found From https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#manual/usage.html